# rxjs WebSocket auto-reconnection on Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, rxjs, observable

How make `rxjs WebSocket Subject` auto-reconnection on socket close(*complete*, *error*) in *Hot Observable* (*multicast*) way?

First of All, I know `rxjs`'s *WebSocket* is for browser. but My Project is *Node.js* Project.

So I replace `rxjs`'s *Websocket* with `ws` module on *npm*

```js
global.WebSocket = require("ws");
```

And My *WebSocket* Server close connection after 3s from initial connection. (for test `rxjs` reconnection)

```js
wss.on("connection", (ws => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(
      JSON.stringify('You are connected')
    );
    setTimeout(() => {
      ws.close();
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Lastly, I connect my own *WebSocket* Server and try reconnect with `retry`.

```js
global.WebSocket = require("ws");
const { webSocket } = require("rxjs/webSocket");
const { retry } = require("rxjs/operators");
const wsSubject = webSocket(`ws://localhost://${port}`); // declared globally as Hot Observable
wsSubject.pipe(retry({ delay: 1500 })).subscribe(console.log);
```

On my code, Initial Connection is established, but There is no re-connection trying.

I think *WebSocket* `Subject` is literally done on connection closed, How can I make *WebSocket* Reconnection as Hot Observable way.

I want to make other `Observables` with `multi-casted` emitted values of my *wsSubject* variable on auto-reconnection environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two situations on end of *WebSocket* Connection.

First Situation is end with `error`. And The Other one is end with `complete`.

First, This is description of `rxjs` `retry` Operator.

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable with the exception of an `error`.

So, `retry` works on `error`. If connection is lost cause of `error`, `retry` works on here.

Second, This is description of `rxjs` `repeat` Operator.

> Repeats all values emitted on the source. It's like `retry`, but for non `error` cases.

So, If 'WebSocket' Connection closed Normally, It means the condition is not `error` but `complete`.

If Connection should be trying reconnection on even `complete` condition, `repeat` would be apt for this.

And Lastly, `share` is operator for `multi-cast`

Then codes should be like below.

```js
global.WebSocket = require("ws");
const { webSocket } = require("rxjs/webSocket");
const { retry, repeat, share } = require("rxjs/operators");
const wsSubject = webSocket(`ws://localhost://${port}`); // declared globally as Hot Observable
wsSubject.pipe(
 share(),
 retry({ delay: 1500 }),
 repeat({ delay: 1500 })
).subscribe(console.log);
```